# What are the pros and cons of learning English from movies and radio?

Tags: learning

I dedicate one to two hours each day to learning English. I'm focusing on listening and speaking (and improving my accent, of course). I want to know what the pros and cons are of learning English from movies and television (usually U.S. series such as *24*, *Lost*, *Prison Break* etc.) and radio (on stitcher.com and other online stations).

Comment: Sorry, I'm voting to close. This is an interesting question by itself, but there is no definitive answer to it, only various opinions, which may only lead to a discussion. Maybe try using the chat and ask people there.

Answer (score 2):

Pros:

- You'll learn pronunciation and accent.
- You'll pick up slang and and vernacular.

Cons:

- You'll learn Hollywood/fit-for-broadcast pronunciation and accent.
- You won't pick up real-life everyday slang and vernacular.
- You won't learn spelling or formal written rules or grammar.

I definitely recommend watching and listening to English TV, films, radio, podcasts and even music from a wide range of sources as part of learning a language, although of course it shouldn't be the only method.

Comment: Actually I am considering to follow an internet radio of English to listen at work when I free. It must be a suitable to understand accent for student of English. Do you know a radio channel I have mentioned? Thanks

Comment: You could try BBC Radio 4, it has a varied selection of mostly spoken content.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Now I am listening the channel. Its English accent but I can listen.